# jquery.smooth-scroll.js Mobile scrolling immediately

Tags: jquery

I am using a parralax effect with the help of: jquery.smooth-scroll.js

(https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll)

On The Mobile when I click a Link it scrolls immediately without the smooth effect

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced it with this library, it is working on Mobiles:

```
    https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll
```